# Read from file and call function

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a task in which I need to read from text file and call a function. The text file is following:

```
black,20,10,3,1
red,10,20,4,3
blue,10,-20,-4,3
```

My defined function takes five parameters, which are split in the text flile by commas.
This is what I have so far:

```
with open(textfile) as source:
    for i in source.readlines():
        a = split(",")
```

But here I have no idea how to call the function with the read line from source.

Any ideas?

Comment: `myfunc(a[0], a[1] ....)`?

Comment: `func(a[0],a[1],a[2],a[3],a[4])`? or more briefly: `func(*a)`?

Comment: But a[0] gives me black, red and blue which is not what I want..

Comment: @teepa: what *do* you want then?

Comment: "my defined function takes five parameters, which are split in the text file by commas" So I want the function to read five different values from one line, jump to next line and read five values and jump to the last line and read the values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up with this and it is working.

```
def piirra_tiedostosta(tiedosto):
    with open(tiedosto) as source:
        for i in source.read().splitlines():
        c, a, r, n, w = i.split(",")
        a = int(a)
        r = int(r)
        n = float(n)
        w = int(w.strip())
```

Now I have all the variables separated from eachother, and I can call the function.

f(c, a, r, n, w)

Answer (score 1):

If your function is `f`, you could simply call `f(*a)`.

Comment: if I do indexes of a, they give me wrong things. For example, a[0] gives me black, red, blue. I would want it to give me black, 20, 10, 3, 1